# ¿Por qué no carga la base de datos en phpMyAdmin que acabo de crear?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Resulta que al momento de dar en el botón **crear** en creación de base de dato de PhpMyAdmin, entrega el mensaje de "Procesando petición".

Se queda ahí y no crea ninguna base de datos. Es mi primera base de datos, acabo de instalar XAMPP, no he hecho ninguna configuración extra, mi navegador es Safari, desactive el firewall, probé cambiando el puerto de 80 a 4000 en servidor Apache y nada.

Nada no quiere crear la Base.

Comment: Prueba a elegir el cotejamiento de la base de datos.

Comment: Prueba realizar los comandos directamente en por consola

Comment: Me darias un ejemplo de como serian los comandos?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes comenzar a trabajar desde la consola, si la instalación de XAMPP te esta dando problemas:

Para trabajar desde la consola, los comandos para creación de bases de datos van del modo siguiente

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS database_name;
```

Una vez que esta hecha tu base de datos y puedas empezar a trabajar sobre ella ejecuta el siguiente comando

```
USE database_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta crear la base de datos desde la consola con este comando:

```
create database `database-name`
```

Si sigue sin funcionar, desinstala XAMPP y vuelvelo a instalar, quizás se haya generado un error con el phpMyAdmin. También intenta actualizar tu phpMyAdmin hasta la última versión, te dejó el enlace para que entres a descargarlo:

https://www.phpmyadmin.net/